# Loading a WebKit view in the Background (Cocoa)

Tags: cocoa, webkit

What is the best way to load a WebView in the background, while leaving other WebViews responsive?

It seems, that whenever you make a loadRequest call, regardless of which thread it is on, or how it is called, it will still process time from your other webviews, making them unresponsive:

```
WebView *webViewA, *webViewB;

// Init, load and present webViewA

// In the background Init, and load (but do not show) webViewB
```

Seems like no matter how I try, sending [[WebViewB mainFrame] loadRequest:request] causes WebViewA to become unresponsive while WebKit is churning away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebKit2 (see announcement email: https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2010-April/012235.html) offers some hope of this, but sadly for now it's not possible as far as I know. WebKit as it exists today is inherently single-threaded.